# Stage DocuSign environment

Tags: docusignapi

In our project we are using **sandbox/demo** DocuSign environment for development

- https://demo.docusign.net/restapi (https://account-d.docusign.com)

In production we're planning to switch to **live/production** DocuSign environment

- https://www.docusign.net/restapi (https://account.docusign.com)

I've come across another **stage** DocuSign environment in the official DocuSign Java Client Library [docusign-java-client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client) ([ApiClient.java#L89](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/5ae12e5972ed5289ed7eedf3ba5cc6332be01651/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/client/ApiClient.java#L89))

```
  /** stage base path */
  public final static String STAGE_REST_BASEPATH = "https://stage.docusign.net/restapi";
```

- https://stage.docusign.net/restapi (https://account-s.docusign.com)

I couldn't find any information on this specific environment. What is it used for and what is the difference between demo, stage and production environments?

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the question here and provide the link for reference. Link-only question can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you saw that, but this is an internal only environment for DocuSign engineers and cannot be used/accessed by anyone who is not working for DocuSign.

We will look into potentially updating the GitHub code to not show this link; will confirm soon.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.

I've seen the link https://stage.docusign.net/restapi [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/5ae12e5972ed5289ed7eedf3ba5cc6332be01651/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/client/ApiClient.java#L89).

This link https://account-s.docusign.com was deduced by me :)

Comment: The official Docusign PHP SDK also mention the staging url https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client/blob/master/src/Client/Auth/OAuth.php